# How to replace a word using php

Tags: php

I have this text: "We - Wednesday will be sunny"

I tried to modify the text using next code:

```
$text = str_replace(array("We","Tu"), "01", $text);
```

The result is not what I want to do:
"**01** - **01**dnesday will be sunny"

I want to change just the word consists of 2 characters. I want to make change in this way:

"**01** - Wednesday will be sunny"

How do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$text = preg_replace('/^We\b/', "01", $text);`

Use Regex to select the 'We' at the start of the string, with an immediate word boundary after.